# Android: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views - UnitTest

Tags: android

I'm designing UnitTest for little app. This app cout what numerology number You are using birth date. I have a problem, I what to invoke method which check number and put value into TextView. I got a error

```
`android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6347)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:871)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1481)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6817)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3947)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3805)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3780)
at com.numerology.MainActivity.showTextInfo(MainActivity.java:168)
at com.numerology.test.Numerology.testMasterNumber(Numerology.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

`

My layout:
`

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:text="Please set the date of Your birth"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Date of your birth (DD-MM-YYYY): "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:text="Description:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/description">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/allInformation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />        
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

My method which I would like to test:
`

```
public void showTextInfo(int number){
        if (number == 1){
            finInformation.setText("People with vibration digits 1, are born leaders, who can     not stand authority over him and wishing at all costs to preserve their independence.     Confident, blockbuster, effective in action, full of charisma, have a really high potential     energy and a sense of independence. They feel a strong need for self-improvement. They are     very creative, able to demonstrate their own initiative, they have no problems with     communicative, able to speak beautifully. Top comes the realization of short-term actions.     \n\n" +
                    "Strength of character, individuality, desire to create, creativity, dominance, bold ideas, persuasive, charisma and outstanding leadership skills to help them in reconciliation of people, which ones indicate the way forward. Ones usually have high authority and are often the model to follow. " + 
                    "They have a practical sense, a strong will, organizational capacity, but smaller executive ability. These are dynamic in nature, characterized by their spontaneity, willingness to take risks. Numerological ambitious ones are those having the ability to self-realization and organizational talent. They are enterprising and intelligent, feel a high need for power, achievement of high social position. " + 
                    "Ones strive for perfection, are self-critical. Not tolerate criticism from others. Their weaknesses, it peremptoriness, a tendency to self-absorption, domination, arrogance, risky behavior, the tendency to impose their own opinions, impatience. \n\n" +
                    "Failures can cause a feeling of frustration, excessive nervousness and explosiveness. In partnership readily show their feelings, they feel a great need to appreciate, may be overly jealous, even possessive. " +
                    "For people with One numerology number it's hard to get a compromise, they prefer to impose their views and way of seeing.");
        }`
```

Comment: As the error says that you are accessing ui thread from non ui thread

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem with adnotation @UiThreadTest before my test method.

Answer (score 0):

put the code where you set value to textview in a new thread;

```
  Handler h=new Handler();
  h.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        textView.setText(value);
        }
   });
```

Looks lile your textview is finInformation use that in run();

Comment: I solved this problem with annotation @UiThreadTest before my test method. Thanks for fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` implementation is as below:

```
   /**
         * @return The activity under test.
         */
        public T getActivity() {
            if (mActivity == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Activity wasn't created yet");
            }
            return mActivity;
        }
```

Since when `getActivity()` returns Activity instance, it means, it must create Activity. When Activity gets created, it must create Activity's View. Activity's View can only be created via `UI Thread`.

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mainActivity = intentsTestRule.getActivity(); / *now Activity's view gets created */
        /* Because Activity's view creation happens in UI Thread, so all the test cases, here, are used by UI Thread */
    }
```

Now, every test cases are **inside the memory of UI Thread**. Hence, you should explicitly use `@UiThreadTest` for every test.

Answer (score 0):

For React Native close performance monitor