# android error in initializing connection using dragonSDK

Tags: android

I am unable to figure out what's going wrong with this code. I am using DragonSDK of Nuance for ASR based android application. I thinks there is some issue with loading a lib file and initialization of connection with the server. I have checked the dependency (.jar) file being present in the libs directory. Also checked the gradle entry for the lib file.

```
   06-29 10:33:35.326  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
    06-29 10:33:35.336  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
    06-29 10:33:35.336  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
    06-29 10:33:35.336  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
    06-29 10:33:35.336  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
    06-29 10:33:35.346  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
    06-29 10:33:41.136  31216-31502/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:33:41.146  31216-31502/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:33:44.426  31216-31502/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:33:44.426  31216-31502/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:33:44.436  31216-31500/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Error creating recorder
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nmsp_sk_speex from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.ashwin.speechtotext-2/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.ashwin.speechtotext-2/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                at com.nuance.nmsp.client.sdk.oem.AudioSystemOEM.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ce.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.bc.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ah.n(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aj.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.af.c(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.b.start(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$5.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.av$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.k.run(Unknown Source)
    06-29 10:33:44.436  31216-31500/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder error
    06-29 10:33:44.436  31216-31500/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Can't stop recorder because it wasn't started
    06-29 10:33:44.446  31216-31500/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Exception in application callback
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6187)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:877)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4334)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11192)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11147)
                at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6688)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3908)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3766)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3741)
                at com.ashwin.speechtotext.Dictation$2.onError(Dictation.java:81)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.i.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$3.onError(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.b$1.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.u$1.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.o.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aa.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ai.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.q.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aj.g(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ah$1$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.av$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.k.run(Unknown Source)
    06-29 10:33:44.446  31216-31500/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder error
    06-29 10:34:34.436  31216-31502/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [bw] Session Idle for too long, longer than [50] ()
    06-29 10:34:34.436  31216-31503/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [g] Socket Read/Available Expception - [java.net.SocketException] Message - [Socket closed]
    06-29 10:36:17.426  31216-31216/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.ashwin.speechtotext, PID: 31216
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.ashwin.speechtotext/com.ashwin.speechtotext.Dictation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3664)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3682)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:139)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.ashwin.speechtotext.Dictation.onDestroy(Dictation.java:61)
                at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5583)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3682)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:139)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    device not found
        --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
    06-29 10:55:11.786    9101-9145/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:55:11.796    9101-9145/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:55:14.116    9101-9145/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:55:14.116    9101-9145/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!
    06-29 10:55:14.126    9101-9143/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Error creating recorder
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load nmsp_sk_speex from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.ashwin.speechtotext-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.ashwin.speechtotext-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]]: findLibrary returned null
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                at com.nuance.nmsp.client.sdk.oem.AudioSystemOEM.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ce.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.bc.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ah.n(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aj.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.af.c(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.b.start(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$5.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.av$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.k.run(Unknown Source)
    06-29 10:55:14.126    9101-9143/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder error
    06-29 10:55:14.126    9101-9143/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Can't stop recorder because it wasn't started
    06-29 10:55:14.136    9101-9143/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Exception in application callback
        android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6187)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:877)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4334)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11192)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11147)
                at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6688)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3908)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3766)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3741)
                at com.ashwin.speechtotext.Dictation$2.onError(Dictation.java:81)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.i.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.c$3.onError(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.b$1.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.u$1.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.o.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aa.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ai.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.q.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.aj.g(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.ah$1$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.av$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                at com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.k.run(Unknown Source)
    06-29 10:55:14.136    9101-9143/com.ashwin.speechtotext E/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder error
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754500/android-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-vi

Comment: Thank you Anoop M but i don't see how it can solve my problem with nmsp_sk_speex or speechKit

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error that triggers the others is "ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!" Check your SpeechKit.initialize that should look like
`SpeechKit.initialize(context,      speechKitAppId,
                                    speechKitServer,
                                    speechKitPort,
                                    speechKitSsl,
                                    speechKitCertSummary,
                                    speechKitCertData,
                                    speechKitApplicationKey);`

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_Android/SpeechKit_Guide/ServerConnection.html

Check also if you have the correct permission :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Lastly, check if the library `libnmsp_sk_speex.so` is added to you project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I can confirm that you need to make sure all of the library folders of .so's (other than just the .jar) are added.

I also changed the initialize to:

SpeechKit.initialize(context,      speechKitAppId,
                                    speechKitServer,
                                    speechKitPort,
                                    speechKitSsl,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    speechKitApplicationKey);

Good luck.